# Check/uncheck click handler only toggles first time

Tags: jquery

I have this code.

```
        var check = true;
        $('#selectall').click(function () {
            $("form input[type='checkbox']").attr ("checked", true);
            if (check){
                check = false;
                $('#checktodos').attr("src", "check_off.png");
            }
            else {
                $('#checktodos').attr("src", "check_on.png");
                $("form input[type='checkbox']").attr ("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

When I click on the button with ID = "selectall", all checkboxes are selected, and the image button changes. Then I click again on the same button, and all checkboes are unchecked and image changes again to the first one.

But I can't do it more times, I make a third click on the button, and the image button doesn't change and no checkboxes are selected. I want to do this unlimited times.

Comment: show associated html or put it in fiddle

Comment: It's because you don't change `check` back to `true` in the else block.

Comment: if i do this only image button changes, in the third click, no more check/unchecked checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your else condition:

```
check = true;
```

You set var check to false, but never back to true.

UPDATE:

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZzUc/

You appear to be using a version of jQuery > 1.5 so you need to use .prop("checked", true); instead of .attr("checked", true);

Comment: with your code, only image button changes, in the third click, no more check/unchecked checkbox

Comment: @frankie4 updated the answer above and included an example for you to try.  It should now be working.